How do I add an audio element in a page?
I'm trying to attach an audio element to the bottom of the page. I tried the following code, but the audio element is not being rendered on the page.
/**                                                                                                                                                                     
 * Implements hook_page_bottom()                                                                                                                                        
 */
function myModule_page_bottom(array &$page_bottom) {
  $path = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('myModule') . '/sounds';
  // Provide markup for the beep sound to notify user.                                                                                                                  
  $soundMarkup = '<audio id="beep"><source src="' . $path . '/tring.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">';
  $page_bottom['myModule'] = [
    '#markup' => $soundMarkup,
  ];
}


You can build this with render elements
  $sound = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'audio',
    '#attributes' => [
      'id' => 'beep',
    ],
    'source1' => [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'source',
      '#attributes' => [
        'src' => 'beep.mp3',
        'type' => 'audio/mpeg',
      ],
    ],
  ];

  $page_bottom['myModule'] = $sound;

or use an inline template. See #markup is replacing colon in <gcse:search... tag with space
